# How to append special characters to a list in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, append, scheme, racket

I am trying to append `(` to an element of a list followed by `)`

How should it be? I am trying the following:

`(append (list 'lambda) (list 'x))` : this compiles and gives the result `'(lambda x)`

I want the result to be:

`(lambda (x))`

Any hint?

Comment: If you're doing this as part of a macro, consider instead using a safer/easier/preferred way like `syntax-rules`, `syntax-case`, or (in Racket) `syntax-parse`. Otherwise, carry on and have fun. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to write it is:

```
(list 'lambda (list 'x))
```

If you really must use the `append` approach mentioned in your question, then one possible solution is:

```
(append (list 'lambda) (list (list 'x)))
```

Comment: Thanks that was quick!